# How to create partly async post request in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post

I'm new to Spring Boot and I would like to create a kind of async request. It should allow user to upload a file. Then Spring application should save it and answer the user that the file was properly saved.

Then the whole async part happens. Server should start processing the file (in background) right after having it saved. Currently, it does not run in background (user needs to wait until `processFileInBackground`finishes):

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ProcessFileController {
    @Autowired
    ProcessFileService processFileService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/files/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("singleFileUpload tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        bytes = file.getBytes();
        // Save file...
        String plainText = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        processFileInBackground(plainText);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("File successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    private void processFileInBackground(String plainText) {
        processFileService = new ProcessFileService(plainText);
        String result = processFileService.getResult();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ProcessFileService {

    private FileProcessor fileProcessor;

    public CompilerApiService(String plainText){
        fileProcessor = new FileProcessor(code);
    }

    @Async
    public String getResult(){
        System.out.println("getResult tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        // The call below takes a long time to finish
       return fileProcessor.getResult();
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig {
    @Bean
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply create a thread to save the file and you can start processing.

Comment: look at the `@Async` annotation e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034828/can-api-request-get-call-return-a-response-to-client-and-start-a-background-ta/56036666#56036666)

Comment: my suggestion is try something post the code here so we can solve the issue

Comment: @Deadpool I posted some code after using the Async annotation, but I still face some problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring offers **@Async** annotation to you, you need to separate your async logic in a separate class and annotate your method with this async, this will execute your logic in a separate thread.
Check this  https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Be ware that you must call the async method from outside the caller class in order to execute in async mode, something like this

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ProcessFileController {
    @Autowired
    ProcessFileService processFileService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/files/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        bytes = file.getBytes();
        // Save file...
        String plainText = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        processFileInBackground(plainText);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("File successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    private void processFileInBackground(String plainText) {
        processFileService = new ProcessFileService(plainText);
        String result = processFileService.getResult();
    }
}
```

Service

```java
@Service
public class ProcessFileService {

    private FileProcessor fileProcessor;

    public CompilerApiService(String plainText){
        fileProcessor = new FileProcessor(code);
    }

    @Async
    public String getResult(){
       return fileProcessor.getResult();
    }

}
```

Configuration

```java
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig {
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
      ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
      executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
      executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
      executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
      executor.initialize();
      return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow that guide, but it didn't work for me - I must have missed something. Could you look at the code? I editted the question

Comment: Compare your code with my edit in my updated answer, this should solve you issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as I expected. I make a POST request to `/files/upload` with a file that needs 9 seconds to process. I need to wait about 9.2 seconds to receive the `ResponseEntity` for that request. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe this is the actual time for file processing, you can check that by placing out statement which display Thread Id to you in getResult method, put
       System.out.println(Thread.CurrentThread().getId())

Comment: I placed that out statement both in `ProcessFileController.singleFileUpload()` and `ProcessFileService.getResult()` method. They both print the same value (26). Should it be like that?

Comment: Still the same :\ Both ids are 26. You can take a look on my edited question, where I added the out statements.

Comment: Your code is not matching mine, remove async from processFileInBackground, and use async only without naming

Comment: Yeah, I have already done that a bit earlier. Updating question only for clarification. Finally - I have one `@Async` in my code, which annotates `getResult()` in service. The ids are still equal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193354/discussion-between-bobszkielaton-and-mohamed-sweelam).

Comment: "Be ware that you must call the async method from outside the caller class in order to execute in async mode" was the most important, it works now, thank you :)

Comment: Is that actually the final solution that worked?